# Do the Left Brain and Right Brain have different functions?

Tags: neurology, logic

I've heard that the left brain controls the logical aspects of the thought and right brain controls the creative. Is there any truth to such claims?

Comment: I heard that more recent studies have disproven the studies performed in the 60s.  I'd love to see the papers if anyone has links.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**No.**

In the case of Left Brain/Right Brain "function" has been interpreted as "thought." Thought and function are not the same thing.

Each hemisphere of the brain has specializations or function sets. Generally:

- Right hemisphere: Processing of
  visual and audiological stimuli,
  spatial manipulation.
- Left hemisphere: Linear reasoning and
  language functions.

How do we know?

> ... definite evidence for language
>   lateralisation arose from studies in
>   split brain patients. In these
>   patients, **the nerve fibres that
>   connect the two hemispheres were
>   severed** in order to stop the spread of
>   epileptic seizures from one hemisphere
>   to the other ... studies of these split
>   brain patients were carried out in the
>   1960s and 1970s by the Nobel Prize
>   laureate Roger Sperry and his
>   colleagues at the Californian
>   Institute of
>   Technology ... Sperry’s
>   experiments yielded an amazing result:
>   when split brain patients processed an
>   object with their right hand, i.e.
>   with their left hemisphere, they could
>   easily name the object. In contrast,
>   when an object was touched with the
>   left hand, i.e. processed by the right
>   hemisphere, they could not name it!

The whole "philosophy" of Left Brain/Right Brain was pulled from this information, not from further research. In other words, it's made up.

> The notion of different hemispheric
>   thinking styles is based on an
>   erroneous premise: each brain
>   hemisphere is specialised and
>   therefore each must function
>   independently with a different
>   thinking style. This connection is a
>   bridge too far: it uses scientific
>   findings regarding functional
>   asymmetries for the processing of
>   stimuli to create conceptions about
>   hemispheric differences on a different
>   level, such as a cognitive thinking
>   style. Furthermore, there is no direct
>   scientific evidence supporting the
>   idea that different thinking styles
>   lie within each hemisphere. Indeed,
>   deriving different hemispheric
>   thinking styles from functional
>   asymmetries is quite a bold venture,
>   which oversimplifies and misinterprets
>   scientific findings.

The above two quotes come from [The left brain/ right brain myth](http://www.oecd.org/document/63/0,3343,en_2649_35845581_34555007_1_1_1_1,00.html).

> Being a neurophysiologist, I suppose I
>    ought to feel that progress has been
>    made: in no other age could it have
>    taken a mere twenty years to shift
>    from a predominantly religious
>    metaphor to a semi-scientific one.
>    But the neurophysiologists and
>    neuropsychologists who specialize in
>    the human cerebral cortex are starting
>    to view the left-righters with
>    something of the wariness which the
>    astronomers reserve for astrology." -William Calvin

Comment: Is it reversed for anyone?  Left-handers?  Situs inversus?

Comment: @endolith: Are you asking if lateralisation of specific functions is reversed for anyone? If so, the answer is yes. In 95% of right-handers language is lateralised to the left-hemisphere, while for left-handers its 70%, with 15% lateralised to the right, and 15% bilateral. That and more data here: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11065-006-9011-9

Comment: Incidentally, for anyone interested, that link I posted is a review of the language functions that the right hemisphere contributes.

Comment: @Solus: Mentioned in this video, too. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBbilBZ46Eg