# Do Vietnamese schools officially require students to write with their right hands?

Tags: psychology, education, children

The Wikipedia article about [bias against left-handed people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people#Discrimination_and_consequences_in_modern_society) states that

> In Vietnam, schools officially require students to write with their right hands, and some teachers of Grade 1 (when writing is taught) would implement that rule by deducting points from tests written by the left hand. The Civic Education textbook for grade 7 mentions a student thanking her old teacher for helping her write with her right hand, and stopping her from using her left hand to write.

Is this claim correct? No citation is provided. I haven't been able to find copies or other discussions of the Vietnamese "Civic Education textbook for grade 7" online, nor any other references to support this.

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7282/22107) and [a recent news story](http://www.ibtimes.com/left-handed-controversy-oklahoma-pre-school-teacher-forces-child-write-right-hand-2108903) sparked my interest in this.

Comment: This was common practice in The Netherlands a generation or two ago.

Comment: It also was harsh for left-handed writers in France up to about 30 years ago. Writing was taught with dip pens, which are very hard to use for left-handed writer and getting lower marks because of stains was common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [vietnamnews.vn](http://vietnamnews.vn/opinion/you-asked/187908/you-asked-12-05-2009.html), the head of the Ministry of Education and Training says that:

> The Ministry of Education and Training has never promulgated any regulation prohibiting pupils from using their left hand for writing